# Can't start Aptana, doesn't find JDK

Tags: aptana

I added this to my .bashrc, still doesn't work:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/java/default/bin"
PATH="$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0/bin"

export JDK_HOME=/usr/java/default
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
>   must be available in order to run AptanaStudio3. No Java virtual machine
>   was found after searching the following locations:
>   /home/pc/Programming/IDEs/Aptana Studio 3/jre/bin/java
>   java in your current PATH

I don't even know what that error means, there is no folder called "jre" inside my Aptana download.

Comment: What operating system are you on? If on Windows, generally people just install the JDK from Sun as an installer and it sets those variable already.

Answer (score -1):

Most people might get this error message while installing Aptana Studio 3 for the first time.

But there is a simple solution for it, just follow these given steps:

1. GO TO [java.com][2]
2. Download the latest JRE for your OS **I prefer both x86 & x64
3. Install it
4. Restart your PC
5. Launch Aptana 3

Comment: Hello Shayaan. welcome to stackoverflow. I have edited your answer to make it clear and readable. Please use the formatting properly and dont delete the links generated by editor. Thanks for contributing.